# Use master pages to change text frame on every page

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, book, master-page

I am currently using InDesign to edit a book that my father wrote and is republishing. He is making some changes, most notably, differently sized pages. I was able to very easily change the size of every page through the master pages, however, now there is a large page with a very small text frame in the center of it. The master pages had the same small text frame, however, when I set the frame in the master page to the desired size and position, the frames with the writing itself, the ones on the actual pages, they don't change. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Two things you can try

- make sure you check 'Enable Layout Adjustment' when you change the size of your master page
- reapply the enlarged master page to all pages

Answer (score 0):

The text frames must have been "unlinked" from the master page somehow. Maybe they have been cut out and pasted in again or maybe their size or position have been changed manually.

If the text frames really do have the same position and size on all pages, here is trick that enables you to change the size of all off them using the master page:

1. Go to the master page.
2. With `Enable Layout Adjustments` turned off, set the margins of the master page so that they snap exactly to the text frame.
3. Now, if you change the margins with `Enable Layout Adjustments` turned on, it should affect all the text frames, even though they are no longer "linked" to the master page.

Answer (score -2):

One quick way to go is making a pdf with text converted to curves and use that resampled inside InDesign.